# React-Native: Streaming audio using a websocket

Tags: react-native, audio, streaming

I am trying to stream audio data in my react-native project. There are some libraries that I have found, but those seem to be either outdated or no longer maintained.

Can I just use a javascript websocket? or do I have to use a socket.io or something? 
And can I use [JavaScript Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) with react-native?